# Set ranged cell value = to another range efficiently

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I'm currently working with

```
Dim ptWS As Worksheet, roneWS As Worksheet, rtwoWS As Worksheet, rthreeWS As Worksheet, rfourWS As Worksheet

Set ptWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PATIENT INFO COPY-PASTE")
Set roneWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RACK 1")
Set rtwoWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RACK 2")
Set rthreeWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RACK 3")
Set rfourWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RACK 4")

roneWS.Range("E6:N6") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B2:B11"))
roneWS.Range("C7:N7") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B12:B23"))
roneWS.Range("C8:N8") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B24:B35"))
roneWS.Range("C9:N9") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B36:B47"))
roneWS.Range("C10:N10") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B48:B59"))
roneWS.Range("C11:N11") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B60:B71"))
roneWS.Range("C12:N12") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B72:B83"))
roneWS.Range("C13:N13") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B84:B95"))

rtwoWS.Range("E6:N6") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("C2:C11"))
rtwoWS.Range("C7:N7") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("C12:C23"))
rtwoWS.Range("C8:N8") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("C24:C35"))
rtwoWS.Range("C9:N9") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("C36:C47"))
rtwoWS.Range("C10:N10") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("C48:C59"))
rtwoWS.Range("C11:N11") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("C60:C71"))
rtwoWS.Range("C12:N12") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("C72:C83"))
rtwoWS.Range("C13:N13") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("C84:C95"))

rthreeWS.Range("E6:N6") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("D2:D11"))
rthreeWS.Range("C7:N7") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("D12:D23"))
rthreeWS.Range("C8:N8") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("D24:D35"))
rthreeWS.Range("C9:N9") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("D36:D47"))
rthreeWS.Range("C10:N10") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("D48:D59"))
rthreeWS.Range("C11:N11") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("D60:D71"))
rthreeWS.Range("C12:N12") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("D72:D83"))
rthreeWS.Range("C13:N13") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("D84:D95"))

rfourWS.Range("E6:N6") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("E2:E11"))
rfourWS.Range("C7:N7") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("E12:E23"))
rfourWS.Range("C8:N8") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("E24:E35"))
rfourWS.Range("C9:N9") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("E36:E47"))
rfourWS.Range("C10:N10") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("E48:E59"))
rfourWS.Range("C11:N11") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("E60:E71"))
rfourWS.Range("C12:N12") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("E72:E83"))
rfourWS.Range("C13:N13") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("E84:E95"))
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this given the weird placement I need the values on all the destination worksheets?

I don't need formats or anything, just the cell values.

Originally I had just made all the cells on roneWS = ptWS cells but that posed an issue when I was test using the document.  So I'm looking for a better way to make a cell value on ws1 to equal cell value on ws2,ws3, and ws4 but in a specific format and import all values to destination worksheets with the click of a button.  Blanks are possible in copy range.

Comment: Side note: you've got some duplicate lines: `rtwoWS.Range("E6:N6") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ptWS.Range("C2:C11"))` for example.